# Is too much charge time bad for your iPhone?

Tags: iphone, charging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I safely charge my iPhone 4 overnight on a regular basis?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/893/can-i-safely-charge-my-iphone-4-overnight-on-a-regular-basis)

Is leaving the phone on the charger overnight really really bad for your iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nah. Electricity is PULLED to devices that use it, not PUSHED from the plug. The phone is smart enough to stop pulling when its battery is full.

EDIT: However, an adapter can provide incorrect voltage for a device. Don't take what I said there and wire your iphone power adapter to a 220 source, for instance. You can OVERDRIVE a device with too many volts, but you can't send it "too much" of the right voltage, because the amperage is a function of the device's draw. I know I just said that assuming that you understand the difference between volts and amps, but there it is; they're different.

Answer (score 3):

No, leaving it charging overnight will not have any adverse effects.  All you need to do with the iPhone's lithium battery is be sure to drain it once a month for longevity.

Read [Apple's iPhone Battery](http://www.apple.com/batteries/iphone.html) page.

[Similar answer for Apple's lithium laptop batteries, iPad batteries, etc.]

Also see [Apple's Lithium-Ion Batteries](http://www.apple.com/batteries/) page for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is it's just like an laptop: If it's left plugged in all the time, then the battery WILL eventually die. So the answer is yes, it's OK to leave it plugged in, but not *all* the time.

Comment: This is not correct. If you leave a laptop plugged in, it is not continually charging the battery - if it was, it would explode! Once the battery is charged, the charging circuit will cut out (or at least cut to a drastically lower voltage). One of the worst things to do to a lithium battery is to continually discharge/charge it, keeping it topped up at 100% will keep it working longer. (For the longest life, discharge it to about 40%, and store it in a cold place)

Comment: Tip 8. But then again, I have been known to misunderstand answers. http://cl.ly/3Tq4

Comment: Tip 8 is correct ("Do not leave a charged battery dormant for long periods of time."). My comment wasn't totally clear: if you are *using* the battery, then you should be keeping it charged. If you are not using the battery, you should drain it to 40%. You should try to avoid draining it completely as much as possible.

Comment: Alright. Sorry about being a stickler about this, but I just want to have clear answers here. :)