# Prevent iPhone from charging while connected to MacBook

Tags: iphone, battery

I want to know if is there a way to prevent my iPhone battery from charging,  when I connect it to my MacBook.

I want to try my applications when I'm working, but I'm afraid that I will damage the iPhone battery.

Comment: This isn't a way to prevent charging, but the answers at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/893/can-i-safely-charge-my-iphone-4-overnight-on-a-regular-basis suggest that overcharging is unlikely to damage your iPhone.

Comment: Damage the battery how? There is no such thing as "overcharging" and having your device connected to a computer or an AC adapter will not harm it in the least.

Answer (score 4):

You won't damage the battery.  Your phone will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try it plugged into a unpowered USB hub? I can't guarantee it will help, but it might work.